# RJ45 over internet

Tags: networking

here is a scenario - I have two sites. Site one have some corporate connection + public internet. Site two have only public internet.

Is there any device which will provide me "long patch cable" so I can have corporate connection at site two? No NAT, something like switch with two ports anywhere in the world.

Thanks for tips

Comment: How about a VPN connection to Site one?

Comment: is it possible to have VPN without different IP networks? One subnet for both sites? How clients know that for example device 192.168.1.101 is at site one and 192.168.1.102 at site two?

Comment: Yes, If you setup a VPN on the router for your 192.166.1.X network then when you connect via VPN you will be given an address local to this network

Comment: I have seen such used at broadcast radio stations to provide Internet at transmitter sites by utilizing a STL (studio-to-transmitter link).

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is a L2 Bridge, think this can be done by SonicWall or other Firewall or Routers.